# Raspberry pi 3 - Can't enable VNC

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vnc

I'm unable to enable VNC on raspberry pi 3, I've tried using preference > raspberry Pi configurations and through terminals raspi-config. It shows me that it has successfully enabled VNC, however if I go back to configurations it's back to disabled. 
Also I'm unable to connect with VNC viewer from my mac.

I've installed vnc server on my raspberry pi with:

```
sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server
```

Is there a file somewhere where I can update this manually?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out when installing real vnc server I left out -y
what fixed everything was adding the below:

```
sudo apt-get install -y realvnc-vnc-server
```

and then rebooting

I found the answer here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=161341

Answer (score 4):

The commands that get run when you enable VNC via either of these methods are as follows:

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

So I would suggest running these from the terminal and seeing if you get any errors reported.

You can also run the following to see if the server is actually running:

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

You should also see the VNC icon in the system tray if the server is running.

Also, if you are using anything other than the RealVNC Viewer on your Mac, then you will need to change the Authentication setting in the VNC Server options to "VNC password" instead of the default "UNIX password", and set a separate password for VNC. I would recommend installing the RealVNC Viewer if you haven't already, since this supports UNIX password authentication, plus encrypted connections.

Comment: thanks Andrew for your help, it helped me on right path because now I knew that the Icons should show up. However what solved it was running
sudo apt-get install -y realvnc-vnc-server
I didn't include the -y and it wasn't working.

Comment: I refered to [this doc](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html) for more information.