# Rapsberry pi 5 - vnc issues: errors, gray screen, black screen, no VNC window showing up, dual instances of :5900

Tags: vnc

I just bought Rpi 5, installed Raspberry pi OS with desktop (without the recommended software), enabled VNC from `sudo raspi-config` but the VNC is not showing up in the Takbar. It is installed, as if I run:
`sudo apt-get install -y realvnc-vnc-server`
It says its already installed.
[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/68092/131717) answer did not start the vnc either, I dont get any errors in the pi when I run these commands but I cant connect to the pi afterwards:

[image: vnc help]

The closest thing to connecting was to run `vncserver-virtual` which gives me an IP 192.168.2.36:1 , where if I try to connect it drops me this error `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject`:

[image: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject]

And if I try to re-connect, no error, gray screen with indications that I connected..:

[image: vnc help2]

I noticed that I had two 5900 ports open (`sudo lsof -i :5900`) thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1741274/vnc-server-port-is-already-in-use) post. And if I run `vncserver -x11` I can see the UI also pops up the error of conflicting ports:
[image: dual 5900 ports open]

So I disabled the auto-start of VNC with the pi, and I opened the vnc on my own every time the pi starts up using the command `vncserver -x11`. I took the Ip from there, but when I tried to connect it showed me black screen like in [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68046/black-screen-using-vnc-with-raspbian-lite) post (With the difference that I dont use Raspbian lite, I use the desktop version)...

[image: black screen]

I re-enabled the auto start of vnc from start/raspberry pi configuration (so not from using the `raspi-config` command) and restarted the pi. Now I already had the ip of the vnc on my computer so I didnt need to start the vnc viewer on the pi, I assume it runs at the background with only one :5900 instance, so I can connect using VNC, and I can see the remote desktop!

So the status is: pi opens with VNC since I have it to auto-start with the pi, it doesnt show the VNC window, but it runs at the background and I connect to it, if it doesn't change its IP.

[image: No vnc window]

Reinstalling vnc with `sudo apt purge realvnc-vnc-server` + `sudo rm -rf /etc/vnc/` because the uninstaller fails to delete it, and re-installing vnc server (downloading it from [their website](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/)) does not solve the issue.

1. Why VNC isnt showing up its window? How can I fix that?
2. How can I see the VNC's IP without using the VNC window?

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post text.

Comment: Do not use apt-get use apt.

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with `apt-get`; it functions more-or-less identically to `apt` for the subset of commands it covers.  WRT VNC problems, I believe people have been having these on Bookworm because the GUI uses Wayland instead of X11, but you can apparently change that via `raspi-config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RealVNC seems it cannot support RPi 5's move to Wayland environment (for now).

[RelVNC's statement](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/14110635000221-Raspberry-Pi-5-Bookworm-and-RealVNC-Connect):

> Our current versions of RealVNC Viewer and RealVNC Server
> unfortunately will not support the RPi 5 platform out-of-the-box as a
> result of Raspberry Pi’s move to a default Wayland environment on
> Debian (Bookworm).
>
> RealVNC has enjoyed being the remote access vendor of choice for the
> Raspberry Pi platform and of course we’re disappointed that the new
> stack precludes us from maintaining continuity there just now. It’s
> worth noting that RealVNC Connect will, of course, continue to work on
> all versions of Raspberry Pi and PiOS prior to the latest RPi 5 and
> Bookworm.
>
> We value our partnership with Raspberry Pi highly and we’re broadly
> supportive of the roadmap items required to see us back on the
> platform as default remote access provider in short order. Without
> providing an exact committed delivery date, we are happy to say that
> we’ll be back up and running on RPi 5 during the first half of 2024.

For now, to connect via VNC, I have disabled the VNC on the pi, and I run the `vncserver-x11` everytime the rpi boots to run the vnc manually. And then I can connect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using X11, Make sure to stop & disable WayVNC via `sudo systemctl stop wayvnc` and `sudo systemctl disable wayvnc` as it comes by default (along with Wayland) in Raspberry Pi OS, release date 12/5/23.

Comment: Im posting an answer based on this: https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/14110635000221-Raspberry-Pi-5-Bookworm-and-RealVNC-Connect